# How to find the number of triplets satisfying the above equation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to find the number of triplets {$a,b,c$} satisfying the above equation? The given equation is -
$3^{a}+8^{b}=11^{c}$. Now we have to find the number of triplets {$a,b,c$} satisfying the above equation? I am trying this question by putting the values {$a,b,c$}. For e.g.- I have put $a=b=c=1$. So, the above equation is getting satisfied very easily. So, we can write that {$a,b,c$}$=${$1,1,1$}. But are any other triplets possible? I mean that how many values of $a,b,c$ are possible for the equation $3^{a}+8^{b}=11^{c}$ ? I have found only one triplet i.e. {$a,b,c$}={$1,1,1$}. Also by putting and checking result will be a very much lengthy process. Is there any way to find the number of numbers of triplets very easily? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Assume for the sake of contradiction that $a > 1$. Then, $9 \mid 3^a$, so $8^b \equiv 11^c \bmod{9}$, or $2^c \equiv (-1)^b \bmod{9}$. This implies that $3 \mid c$. Since $11^c \equiv 1331^{c/3} \equiv 1^{c/3} \equiv 1 \bmod{7}$ and $8^b \equiv 1^b \equiv 1 \bmod{7}$, this forces $7 \mid 3^a$, which is impossible.

Thus, we must have $a = 1$ and $3 + 8^b = 11^c$. Next, assume for the sake of contradiction that $b, c > 1$, then we yield $3+8^b \equiv 0 \bmod{121}$, which is equivalent to $b \equiv 11 \bmod{110}$. In particular, this means $11 \mid b$. However, we would then have $8^b \equiv 1 \bmod{23}$, so $11^c \equiv 4 \bmod{23}$, and this yields $c \equiv 20 \bmod{22}$. In particular, $2 \mid c$, so $11^c \equiv 1 \bmod{4}$. However, this would imply that $8^b \equiv 2 \bmod{4}$, which is a contradiction. We can thus conclude that $(a, b, c) = (1, 1, 1)$ is the only triple of solutions in positive integers.

EDIT $1$: As mentioned in the comments by Calvin Lin, if you are interested in all triples of solutions in non-negative integers, the answer is still only $(1, 1, 1)$. We must check the case $a = 0$ where we have $1 + 8^b = 11^c$. Looking at the equation modulo $4$ tells us that $2 \mid c$. However, this implies that $11^c \equiv 1 \bmod{3}$, so $3 \mid 8^b$, which is a contradiction.

EDIT $2$: Thank you to Calvin Lin for pointing out that it should be $b \equiv 11 \bmod{121}$ instead of $b \equiv 10 \bmod{121}$.

Comment: Wolfram says that [$b\equiv 11 \pmod{110}$.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=8%5Eb+%3D+-3+mod+121)

Comment: @CalvinLin Oh, thank you for pointing out my error! Shall I delete my answer?

Comment: You might be able to fix it? I haven't looked much further, was just double checking your statements.

Comment: Perhaps one could conclude that since $11 \mid b$, we have $8^b \equiv 1 \bmod{23}$, so $11^c \equiv 4 \bmod{23}$ and this gives $c \equiv 20 \bmod{22}$, in particular, $2 \mid c$. But then we get $3 + 8^b \equiv 1 \bmod{4}$, which is a contradiction?

Comment: That looks good.